# Un-flatten Eigen::VectorXd to Eigen::MatrixXd

Tags: c++, eigen

Let's say I have a 6-dimensional `Eigen::VectorXd`

```
Eigen::VectorXd flat;
flat.resize(6);
flat << 1,2,3,4,5,6;
```

I want to un-flatten this into a 2x3-dimensional `Eigen::MatrixXd`

```
1,2,3,
4,5,6
```

How is this done most efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about efficiency, but this would work:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> M(flat.data(), 3, 2);
Eigen::MatrixXd M2(M.transpose());
```

Your matrix M2 is the desired matrix.

Comment: Mapping it as a row matrix and then copy would be less cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

A more direct variant (internally, cantordust's answer boils down to the same):

```
typedef Matrix<double,Dynamic,Dynamic,RowMajor> RowMatrixXd;
MatrixXd M = RowMatrixXd::Map(flat.data(), 2, 3);
```